# How to persist in database using MultiSelectListPreference and ListPreference

Tags: android, database, persist, listpreference, android-multiselectlistpreference

I use the preferencescreen to build theview for my application and I want to persist the data into the databases. Please, how can I do this?

Is there a good tutorial that can help me to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can save your app data in Three ways.

1. In Shared preferences [Private to your application]: In key value format.
2. In File: In internal storage [Private to your application] and In external Storage [That does not mean it has to be external SD card]
3. Cloud storage via network.

A good tutorial to start with: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html